how to find the normal vector of a drawn (made of squares/pixels) surface?
I have a project where I need to implement physics with drawn structures. I need to come up with or find an existing algorithm that can find the normal vector at a point on the surface of an image (BufferedImage)
I have an idea that it is possible to somehow find the air pixels around from 1 point on the surface (if it lies on the surface), and use them to find the surrounding physical pixels. But this approach has 2 problems: 1) This approach will not always return the correct coordinates 2) This approach will not always return 2 coordinate points
example 1

example 2


I think you're going to need to narrow down the scope of this question a bit. Can you make a complete example? I think the common approach is to get a couple of the points. Fit a curve to those points, and then use a formula that tells the normal for a point along that curve.

for example, I have a matrix where 1 is an object and 0 is air. And in this matrix lies an arbitrary figure of ones. How can I, given a point on this figure, find the plane on which it lies?

You might want to investigate not drawing a bitmap but a svg. This way you can use the bezier curves of the svg to base your math upon.

The main idea of ​​the project is the interaction of a game with a picture (a matrix of pixels). It is necessary that the player can make the level himself in paint

I've told you how to solve this. Look in the neighborhood, find the points that are edges. Fit a curve to the edges and use that curve to find the normal. Your curve could even be a straight line. What do you want for an answer? Somebody to write a program that loads a buffered image then finds the normal at random points in the image? Your scope is just too large. Turn this into a programming question and somebody would gladly answer it.
